# Install yarn and npm in WSL

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows 10. Then I followed [this](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-yarn-packege-management-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-18-10/) to install yarn:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install curl
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install yarn
```

It did not raise any error. However, `yarn --version` returned

```
$ yarn --version
/mnt/c/Users/chengtie/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn: 12: /mnt/c/Users/chengtie/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn: node: not found
```

`npm --version` returned

```
$ npm --version
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 3: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
: not foundram Files/nodejs/npm: 5: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm:
/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: 6: /mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at this:

```
/mnt/c/Users/chengtie/AppData/Roaming/npm/yarn: 12
```

It is looking for the yarn installed on Windows. You must uninstall yarn from windows or remove it from the WSL's PATH.

Use the following to remove windows yarn from the PATH:

```
WIN_YARN_PATH="$(dirname "$(command -v yarn)")"
export PATH="$(echo "${PATH}" | sed -e "s#${WIN_YARN_PATH}##")"
```

You can add this to your .bashrc

Also, look at your error messages it is getting also npm from windows, you need to remove them from the path using the same technique.

Comment: Caution, in some cases, all `\$` must be `$`

Comment: In fact, the \ must be removed. The code didn't work literally. After 4 years :D

Answer (score 5):

You need to type:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 3):

You must install nodejs before

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: I did. `nodejs --version` returned `v4.2.6`.

Comment: @SoftTimur Maybe you could try install yarn with ``sudo npm install -g yarn``

Comment: `sudo npm install -g yarn` returned `sudo: npm: command not found`.

Comment: Well two possibilies, you can install npm with ``sudo apt-get install npm `` or you can make sure your env variable $PATH is linked with you linux bin directories

Comment: Indeed, I need to do both: `sudo apt-get install npm`, and remove npm and nodejs in Windows from `$PATH`

Answer (score 1):

### If you have latest nodejs version installed:

I encountered the same issue and it got fixed by trying `sudo npm -v` and to get npm without sudo, I **restart**ed the WSL.

### If you don't have the latest nodejs version:

If you are on WSL, you can install the Latest stable version by

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -`

In place of `setup_8.x` you can keep `setup_16.x` for version 16 (which includes npm).

`sudo apt-get install nodejs`

check nodejs version by `nodejs -v`.
check npm version by `npm -v`.

If still the same error codes. try `sudo npm -v` or restart PC/ WSL then try `npm -v`.

Comment: It does turn out a restart was necessary and sufficient for me too.

Answer (score 1):

if you already has NodeJS v16.10 or higher, then

```
corepack enable
```

otherwise you can install corepack beforehand

https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install